# SQL error on restoring database

Tags: mysql, sql, backup

I am running a database backup -- a 7 MB SQL -- using the phpMyAdmin  Import function -- and getting an error, whose text  doesn't really show where the problem is.

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `wp_clbo_bup_files` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pi' at line 1
```

The SQL backup was generated by the Ready! Backup WP plugin, and I would use their plugin GUI, but it doesn't seem to allow uploading an SQL from disk, just loading in backups stored on their system or other cloud services.

Any ideas on how to get this SQL backup to run?

Comment: You'll have to ask whoever wrote the plugin that makes the wp_clbo_bup_files table.  That said, why not just log into phymyadmin on wherever you're making the back *from* and just export it that way if you're having issues with a file generated by a plugin?  Or you could [export it from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3031414/1473550).

Comment: I can't make any more backups because my  WP installation is gone. That's why I need to restore my backups. However, I am hoping that I can get these backups to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is just go direct into your phpmyadmin and export your database [image]

Comment: I can't make any more backups because my WP installation is gone. That's why I need to restore my backup. However, I am hoping that I can restore from my backup SQL.